# GA Reporting API JSON Result Parsing

Tags: javascript, json, google-analytics, reporting

Im fairly new to Javascript, so please be gentle.

Im able to retrieve a jSON response from GA, as shown below.

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": [
          "ga:fullReferrer"
        ],
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:users",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "(direct)"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "38"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "bing"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "facebook.com/"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "10"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "google"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "8"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "l.facebook.com/"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "4"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "l.instagram.com/"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "4"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "m.facebook.com/"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "18"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "m.facebook.com/l.php"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "nestdiapers.com/stockists"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "sundelife.co/"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "2"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "totals": [
          {
            "values": [
              "87"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rowCount": 10,
        "minimums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "1"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "maximums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "38"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now it shows just fine in my browser, using..

```
function displayResults(response) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').innerHTML = json;
}
```

So my dilemma here is when I try to parse a particular result I get an undefined.

Returns Undefined

```
function displayResults(response) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    alert(json.totals.values);
}

or any combination or anything past json.
alert(json.reports.data.rows.metrics[1].values);

This shows the results
alert(json);
```

What am I missing here to get the totals or anything?

Answer (score 0):

your `json` is a string value returned by `JSON.strinfigy()`
to access reported values refer explicitly to returned `response` object and loop through the nested properties, like

```
var reports = response.result.reports
for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
  var report = reports[i]
  console.log(report.columnHeader.dimensions.join(',') + ':' +
  report.columnHeader.metricHeader.metricHeaderEntries.map(function (header) {return header.name} ).join(','))
  for (var j = 0; j < report.data.rows.length; j++) {
    var row = report.data.rows[j]
    console.log(row.dimensions.join(',') + ':' +
    row.metrics.map( function (metric) {return metric.values.join(',')}) )
  }
}
```

This might require some tedious coding, so please refer to JS docs on working with objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects